# How to change text color & background in mac terminal?

Tags: macos, unix, colors, terminal

I'm writing a program that needs to write text in different colors.
I have the escape code RED "`\e[31m".` However, if I make red on a red background, that won't work. So I also want to change the background color.
I've tried using this `"\e[31m\e[94m`" or even `\e[4Xm` to do text on a different background, however, this isn't working. Any ideas to get red text on a white background?

This is in the format std::cout << "COLORNAME" ....

Thanks!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Comment: I get that the 30+i and 40+i are different, but I can't chain them together when doing a print?

Answer (score 4):

Multiple SGR options *can* be chained together, and in fact more compactly than you've been trying. The SGR syntax takes the general form of:

> `\e[` <kbd>options</kbd> `m`

where <kbd>options</kbd> can consist of one* or more numbers separated by semicolons, which can include a number of things, but especially:

- 1: bold
- 30 – 37: set foreground color 0 – 7 (black, red, green, yellow, blue, magenta, cyan, white)
- 40 – 47: set background color 0 – 7 (ditto)
- 90 – 97: set foreground color 8 – 15 (bright versions of 0 – 7; "bright black" is a dark gray)
- 100 – 107: set background color 8 – 15 (ditto)

In your case, red text on a white background would be `\e[31;47m`.

---

(*: Or no numbers at all, in which case it resets all graphical options.)