# Bashrc colours for mac terminal

Tags: linux, macos, terminal, bash

I am trying to create files for dev and prod connections so the colour format is green text black background and red text black background respectively

I have created a profile which looks as follows for dev having followed this guide [How to change text color & background in mac terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089180/how-to-change-text-color-background-in-mac-terminal)

```
PS1='[\d \t \u@\h:\w ] $ \e[31m\e[40m'
```

It successfully creates the text in a red colour and the background colour is black. The issue is that some commands default back to a white background while some maintain a black one.

[image]

How can i fix this?

Thanks

Comment: In general, I agree with Etan's answer, but if it's just (or mostly) `ls`, you can set `alias ls='ls --color=never'`. although on some platforms `ls`'s default is without colors, so make sure you don't already have an alias that makes `ls` colorful that you can simply remove.

Comment: Indeed, if you just don't want any ls colors at all that will solve the `ls` color problem. But not the general problem.

Comment: You can also change in the `Terminal.app` preferences the colorscheme. There are many examples, like "Ocean", "Man page" and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do that by not abusing the fact that you can get formatting to "fall off" the end of your prompt and instead by changing the default color palette of your terminal to replace the default foreground and background colors.